# Navigation Drawer in compose is hiding my content?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, navigation-drawer, slidingdrawer, scaffold

```
                ModalNavigationDrawer(
                    drawerState = drawerState,
                    drawerContent = {
                        ModalDrawerSheet(
                            drawerShape = RectangleShape,
                            drawerTonalElevation = 4.dp,
                            drawerContainerColor = White,
                            drawerContentColor = secondaryColor,
                            content = {
                                NavigationDrawerItem(
                                    label = { drawerNavItems[0].title },
                                    selected = true,
                                    onClick = {  },
                                icon = {
                                    Image(painter = painterResource(drawerNavItems[0].id), contentDescription = "")
                                })
                            }
                        )
                    },
                    gesturesEnabled = true,
                    content = {
                        Scaffold(
                            content = {
                                scope.launch {
                                    drawerState.open()
                                }
                            }
                        )
                    }
                )
```

Later i have this

```
content = {
                Column(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxSize()
                        .background(Color(0xff8d6e63)),
                    verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
                    horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
                ) {
                    CreateAlbum(albumViewModel, it)
                }
            }
```

when i comment the above code the content appears but doesn't when i uncomment it. And the drawer is by default open even when i used DrawerValue.Closed.

I tried debugging into CreateAlbum compose and it is going there.

Comment: Provide a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Add more info on what is hidden.